# Retrieving 24-hour Historic Token Balance in Ethereum (or Arbitrum) with MetaMask and Rabby Wallets

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js, metamask

I'm working on a project where I need to find the balance of a specific token (not necessarily ETH) from 24 hours ago for a connected account. I have the block number from 24 hours ago from BE. Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
export const getTokenBalanceByBlock = async (
  account: string,
  blockNumber: number,
  contractAddress: string,
  tokenPriceInETH: number,
): Promise<number> => {
  const tokenAbi: AbiItem[] = [
    {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [{ name: '_owner', type: 'address' }],
      name: 'balanceOf',
      outputs: [{ name: 'balance', type: 'uint256' }],
      type: 'function',
    },
  ]

  try {
    const web3 = new Web3(_window.ethereum)
    if (contractAddress) {
      const tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(tokenAbi, contractAddress)
      const tokenBalanceWei = await tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(account).call({}, blockNumber)
      console.log({ tokenBalanceWei })
      const tokenBalance = divideOnWei(tokenBalanceWei)
      return tokenPriceInETH ? tokenBalance * tokenPriceInETH : tokenBalance
    } else {
      const ethBalanceWei = await web3.eth.getBalance(account, blockNumber)
      const ethBalance = divideOnWei(ethBalanceWei)
      return ethBalance
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)   
  }
}
```

This approach works fine when the user is connected via MetaMask. However, I encounter issues with the Rabby wallet and when the user switches to the Arbitrum Network. With Rabby wallet:
{
"code": -32000,
"message": "missing trie node 907b6....fd2 (path ) state 0x907...8fd2 is not available, not found"
}
Or when switching to the Arbitrum Network, I get the same error.

1. Is there a more efficient or reliable method to retrieve a 24-hour historic token balance for specific account?
2. How can I address the errors encountered with the Rabby wallet and when switching to the Arbitrum Network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Historical state](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/84200/620) needed to fetch a token balance at a specific block is only available at archive nodes.

- Get an archive node, either from a software-as-a-service provider or run yourself (10TB+ disk needed). For a provider list see [ethereumnodes.com](https://ethereumnodes.co)
- Create a JSON-RPC endpoint for your application on this nod
- Query the historical balance using your own node

You are hijacking your wallet's RPC connection. Whatever RPC connection you get from your wallet does not give you any guarantees you can use it for much of anything.

Comment: Thanks for your advice about using archive nodes. I wasn't aware of this requirement and will look into it. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be:

- to fetch the `Transfer` events of a Token for the Account (`from` and `to` parameters are `indexed` parameters). You can specify also the `fromBlock` number to fetch the blocks from the last 24 hours.
- to get the current balance for the Account
- to re-calculate the balance for the block, as you have the balance change events and current balance.

For this approach, you won't need the archive node, and fetching events with such strict filters for the past 24-hour blocks usually even for the public nodes is not the problem.